# Remove all selected HTML element with innerText using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to parse html tags and want to remove <select> from code which is given in TextArea1 and want to show output in TextArea2 on button click.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
    <textarea id="TextArea1" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />
    <textarea id="TextArea2" rows="10" cols="100"></textarea><br />
    <input id="Submit1" onclick="parsehtml()" type="submit" value="submit" />
    <script>
        function parsehtml()
        {
            document.getElementById("TextArea2").value = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value.replace(/<\/?[^>]+>/ig, " ");
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

In my `TextArea1` i have code like

```
<span>Span 1</span>
<select>
<option>opt 01</option>
<option>opt 02</option>
</select>
<span>Span 2</span>
<select>
<option>opt 11</option>
<option>opt 12</option>
</select>
```

This code return output like:

```
 Span 1 
 opt 01 
 opt 02 
 Span 2 
 opt 11 
 opt 12
```

Please help me to remove all `<select>...</select>` with all of it's <option> with `innerText` and want to output like this:

```
Span 1 Span 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here updated version with different approach. We create new html element from the input value and and get span elements textContent.

```
function parsehtml()
{
    let value = document.getElementById("TextArea1").value
    let html = document.createElement('html');
    html.innerHTML = value
    let spans = Array.from(html.getElementsByTagName( 'span' ))
    let result = spans.map(span => span.textContent)
    document.getElementById("TextArea2").value = result.join(' ')
}
```

Comment: what if i have all code in a single line eg <select><option>opt 1</option></select><span>sdf</span>...

Comment: your code is not working if i have minified or single line code in my TextArea1.

Comment: Updated the solution for single line / minified.